# How do I get angular 2 deep linking working with bearer tokens in Visual Studio 2015 with dot net core?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, angular2-routing, deep-linking

I am currently trying to get an angular 2 application up and running, but I am having some trouble with the basics. At the moment, I have a problem with deep linking. My application can be found on github [here](https://github.com/tonywr71/Snazzle) and is currently a working angular 2 application. I have also attempted to implement authentication using bearer tokens, which may be interfering.

So the trouble with deep linking is that if I am within the application and I navigate between the pages, the router is changing state correctly. However if I try to put in the url to a page, then it fails to load that page, and will redirect to the login page as though I am not logged in.

In the Startup.cs file, I do have the following code:

```
//The following code enables angular 2 deep linking
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
  await next();

  if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 
   && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
  {
    context.Request.Path = "/"; // Angular root page here 
    await next();
  }

});
```

This code will get any url it receives, and if there is no file found at that location, it will redirect to the "/" path, which is where the router is supposed to kick in.

But for some reason, it always ends up back at the login page, instead of going to the actual page requested.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you call `next()` twice? The first one already process the request, why would you call it within the if-block again?

Comment: Also, how did you set up your routes? By default angular uses path segments for navigation. When you hit enter, a request will be done to ASP.NET Core application. Depending on your route, it won't found the path, since there is no controllers except the default one which serves the app. What are you using to server sided? Microsoft's JavaScriptServices (it's AngularServices or SpaServices)?

Comment: Ok I have a variation of that code, which is like this: app.Run(async context =>
      {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        await context.Response.SendFileAsync("./wwwroot/index.html");
      });  which would always serve up the index page.

Comment: I am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.AngularServices : "1.0.0".

Comment: oops, I mean I am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.AngularServices : "1.0.0-*". (missed the -star)

Comment: just discovered /home works /counter doesn't. /counter redirects to the login page. /home takes me directly to the home page without authentication. I must have some sort of anonymous setting on the home page I think.

Comment: Here is a link to my app.routing page: https://github.com/tonywr71/Snazzle/blob/master/Snazzle.UI/ClientApp/app.routing.ts

Comment: ok, I found that the code was performing a permission check in my custom UserProfile class. It was always resulting in a fail from a deep link, and so was redirecting back to the login page. I will have to fiddle further to see if I can get it to auto login.

Comment: That's what I meant in my 2nd comment. You have a controller named "HomeController", so a route /home will be found and returns 200. You don't have a `CounteController`, so MVC can't find it and returns 404, so you get redirected to /

Comment: I realise why I call next twice. The first one  processes the request and if the request gets an error because the requested url does not exist, then it will set it to the default page and then call next on that.

Comment: And how is that supposed to work? The first time `next()` is called it may or may not write data to the response and set headers. When you call it a second time, the data was already written in the data stream, you can't change the headers or remove the previous data as it was most likely already flushed to the client (unless you swapped the streams and first write in a memory stream, which is not very efficient though)

Comment: Also, I don't have a Controller on the server. Mvc is not necessary for the website. My api controllers are in a separate project. Only content appears on the website.

Comment: It's only when it gets a 404 (not found)  that it does the secondary processing. There would be no headers or content for a 404 in the stream.